# Dialogflow chatbot that will give AQI levels

Tags: flutter, air, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I'm building a chatbot using Google's dialogflow. I want to give the user the appropriate AQI value when the user gives location and also the level of some pollutants around the area. How can I do that?

I actually built a chatbot that gives mitigation measures and sources of some major pollutants. Now I also want to give AQI level, levels of some major pollutants by using information from internet. How can I do that?Is it possible?